# Calculating Percent Difference with zero and near zero values

Tags: percentages

I'm trying to calculate the percent difference between an expected measurement and the actual measurement. I'm using the formula

```
Percent Difference = ((Measured value - Expected value)) / Expected value) * 100
```

So if I measure a value of 23, and I expected a value of 20:

```
Percent Difference = ((23-20)/20) * 100 
Percent Difference = 15
```

And I get a negative value if the measured value comes in below the expected value:

```
Percent Difference = ((17-20)/20) * 100 
Percent Difference = -15
```

I"m assuming this is the best way to calculate a percent difference. But what do I do if the expected value is 0 (I can't divide by zero). The above calculation gives works for larger numbers, but gives me really large values as I approach zero.

If I'm expected a value of zero, but get something close (AKA 0.5), if I approximate zero with a small number, I get a crazy value

```
Percent Difference = ((0.5-0.001)/0.001) * 100
Percent Difference = 49900
```

Or even

```
Percent Difference = ((0.5-0.1)/0.1) * 100
Percent Difference = 400
```

Is there a better way to characterize a difference with small numbers?

Comment: The better way to characterize the difference with small numbers is to use the difference between the small numbers. Instead of a ratio, just use the difference itself. Relative error, which is what you are measuring with the percent difference is good when you are multiplying or dividing measurements, but these operations are ill-behaved near $0$. Absolute error (the difference itself) is good when you are adding or subtracting measurements, and is well-behaved on all scales.